# Why i am getting null value when i am mocking or Inject the object .?

Tags: spring, web-services, unit-testing

I am getting a null value when i am trying to Inject the Dao interface.
Sample of code here when i am writing a test cases.

```
@Mock
private ServiceUriLocator serviceLocator;   
@Mock
private SessionDao sessionDao;
ActiveSession session;
AccountData accountdata;
@InjectMocks
Account account
```

This Above code when i am using inside Method like

```
@Test
public void testActivate()
 {
  Response response=account.activate(accountdata).
 }

 private Accountdata accountdata(){
 accountdata.setFirstName("Employee_name");
 accountdata.LastName("Employee_Last_Name");
 return accountdata;
    }
```

In above code account value is null that's why i am getting null pointer exception.
Anybody can calrify why i am getting null value for injecting the mock value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors while executing a test case using mock frameworks.

1. Is Runner setup ? Which runner are you executing with?
   It has to be `MockitoJunitRunner` that helps to run with Mocks
2. `when` statement is written on the same mock object ?
   This has to match with same mock object
3. Is the input string/data match the `when` statement ?
   This has to be same input

> when(service.execute('hi')).thenReturn();

is different from

> when(service.execute('hello')).thenReturn();

4. Where is the `when` written ? `setup - @Before` level or test method level ?

The Global statements written applies to all the test methods, so be careful while you make the `when` statements in the `@Before` method.

These are some of the debug points.

Comment: These are debugging factor what about null value??

Comment: @Ankit, The point here is to check with all these steps. Consider reformatting of your question to add more details.